# Positive and Negative numbers in String

Tags: java

I have to make a program that allows the user to enter integer numbers until he press '0'. The program has to print:
1)The total number of the entered numbers
2) The number of the positive ones
3) The average of the positive ones
4) The number of the negative ones
5) The sum of the negatives

So far, all I could do is make the "enter untill '0' is pressed" and find the number of the entered numbers, which is a lot for me and my programing skills. I am having troubles trying to find out if the number is positive or negative. Probably I am not comparing them right, so I would love if I get a little help from someone advanced.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.*; 

class Nums { 
  public static void main(String args[])  
    throws IOException 
  { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                            InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String str;
    int EnteredNumbers = -1;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    double AveragePositive = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
    do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();

    } while(!str.equals("0")); 
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
  } 
}
```

Comment: `boolean isNeg=false; if(str.startsWith("-")){ str=str.substring(1); isNeg=true; } int NUMBER=Integer.parseInt(str); if(isNeg) { NUMBER*=-1; }` Something like this ?

Comment: Btw, be careful about good practices to name variables. They shouldn't be  Capital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as pointed out `Integer.parseInt` is used in java to convert from `String` to `int`.
Secondly you need to have a extra variable to store and accumulate the total of positive numbers too. I have added a `try-catch` exception block to handle errors.

Here is a code for reference.

```
import java.io.*; 

public class Nums { 
  public static void main(String args[])  
    throws IOException 
  { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                            InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String str;
    int EnteredNumbers = -1;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    int PositiveSum = 0; // Added extra variable
    double AveragePositive = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
   try{
    do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();

    int num = Integer.parseInt(str);


    if (num>0)
      {
        Positive++;
        PositiveSum+=num;
      }
      else if (num<0)
      {
        Negative++;
        NegativeSum+=num;
      }
    } while(!str.equals("0")); 
    AveragePositive = (double)PositiveSum/(double)Positive;
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
    }
    catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong format");
    }  

} 
}
```

Output if there are no errors

```
Enter '0' to quit.
Enter Numbers: 
1
5
5
-5
-5
0
You have have entered 5 numbers!
You have have entered 3 Positive numbers!
The Average of the Positive Numebers is 3.6666666666666665!
You have have entered 2 Negative numbers!
The Sum of the Negative numbers is -10!
```

Comment: You are amazing! There is only one problem left - if I enter double number, a letter or I just press enter the program should give me a Invalid format messsage...

Comment: Also if you enter:
1
5
5
you get 3 as average positive and it should be 3.66

Comment: Try enter 1 5 5 -5 -5 and check the average

Comment: @Monster Have edited it again. Made a change while calculating average

Comment: Thank you so much! It's perfect now!

Comment: I got curious if there is  a way to save in a text file the System.out.printlns?

Comment: @Monster It is there, but you will have to ask it as a separate question as it is unrelated. Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file). They are good posts on writing into files. If you still have any doubts, then you can post a new question. All the best

Comment: looks like I have reached my question limit and I cant ask new question, but here

Comment: @Monster You will have to wait for some time till you ask a new question. That is the rules of SO, I can't help

Answer (score 1):

check by parsing String to int

```
Integer.parseInt(str)>0  //positive number
Integer.parseInt(str)<0 //negative



do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();
      int number= Integer.parseInt(str);
      if(number>0){  //do positive stuffs}
      else if(number<0){//do negative stuffs}
    } while(!str.equals("0"));
```

Comment: I already tried to do that, but it seems I am messing something with the code because it keeps giving me errors...

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code achieves what you want to do

```
import java.io.*; 

class Nums { 
  public static void main(String args[])  
    throws IOException 
  { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                            InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String str;
    int EnteredNumbers = -1;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    double AveragePositive = 0;
    double PositiveSum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
    do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();
      if(Integer.parseInt(str) > 0){
          Positive++;
          PositiveSum = PositiveSum + Integer.parseInt(str);
          AveragePositive = PositiveSum/Positive;
      }
      if(Integer.parseInt(str) < 0){
          Negative++;
          NegativeSum = NegativeSum + Integer.parseInt(str);
      }

    } while(!str.equals("0")); 
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and keep adding the numbers into List. You should do something like:

```
List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

do { 
  str = br.readLine();
  int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
} while(number != 0);
```

And then use for loop to do count like:

```
int negativeNumberSum = 0;
int positiveNumberSum = 0;
int positiveNumberCounts = 0;
for (int i =0; i<numberList.size(); i++) {
    if (numberList.get(i) >= 0) {
        positiveNumberSum += numberList.get(i);
        positiveNumberCounts ++;
    } else {
        negativeNumberSum += numberList.get(i);
    }
}

//print average of positive as positiveNumberSum /(double) positiveNumberCounts if positiveNumberCounts != 0
//print average of positive as negativeNumberSum / (double)(numberList.size() - positiveNumberCounts) same if (numberList.size() - positiveNumberCounts) != 0
//print positive count as positiveNumberSum  and same for negative.
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Integer.parseInt()` to get an `int` from your string `str`, and checking to see if the integer is `< 0` (negative) or `> 0` (positive)

Answer (score 0):

I have added an extra variable called `PositiveSum` to assist with the `AveragePositive` calculation.

In order to perform this calculation, you need to ensure the value is an `Integer` so I have added the parse statement.

```
class Nums { 
  public static void main(String args[])  
    throws IOException 
  { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                        InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String str;
    int EnteredNumbers = -1;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    int PositiveSum = 0; 
    double AveragePositive = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
    do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();
      int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
      if(number<0) {
          Negative++;
          NegativeSum += number;
      } else if(number>0) {
          Positive++;
          PositiveSum += number;

      }

    } while(!str.equals("0"));
      AveragePositive = PositiveSum / EnteredNumbers;
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `do-while` loop: it is using *Strings*, not *integers*:

```
do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      num = sc.nextInt();

    } while(num != 0);
```

Also, you need to `import` the `scanner` utility:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Don't use a `BufferedReader`, but use:

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also, you would want to use a checker for your positive and negative numbers inside your `do-while` loop:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(num)<0) { Negative++; }
else { Positive++; }
```

I've also added a `try-catch` statement to handle an error if someone doesn't enter an `int`:

```
      try {
      num = sc.nextInt();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Invalid integer"); System.exit(0); }
```

I added a little bit of code that takes the `0` off when it prints the numbers, as I realise it will include `0` when you type it in to exit.
Change your `class` statement to `public`, it's just programming:

```
public class Nums {
```

Also, I add a negative-number counter in the main code, and an averager.
Here is the complete code, to avoid confusion:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prime { 
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String args[])  
  { 
    int EnteredNumbers = 0;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    double AveragePositive = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int PosTotal = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
    do { 
      try {
      num = sc.nextInt();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Invalid integer!"); System.exit(0); }
      if(num<0) { Negative++; NegativeSum += num; }
      if(num>0){ Positive++; PosTotal += num; }
      EnteredNumbers++;
    } while(num != 0); 
      AveragePositive = PosTotal / Positive;
      EnteredNumbers -= 1;
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numbers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
  } 
}
```

Hope it helps!
Note I have trial-tested it, and it works brilliantly. If you have any errors with this please tell me :)